# Chemical potential of mixtures of ideal gases and the Gibbs-Duhem equation

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, solutions

As is well known for a constant composition system, $\mu$ (symbolizing chemical potential) is equal to the molar Gibbs energy. Using
$$
\mathrm{d}G = V\mathrm{d}p-S\mathrm{d}T,
$$
we can write
$$
\mu = \mu^{0} + RT\ln P.
$$
But for mixtures,
$$
\mathrm{d}G = V\mathrm{d}p - S\mathrm{d}t + \mu_{\ce{A}} \mathrm{d}n_{\ce{A}} + \mu_{\ce{B}} \mathrm{d}n_{\ce{B}}
$$
Can the original formula for chemical potential in the case of mixtures?

Moreover, using the [Gibbs-Duhem equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%E2%80%93Duhem_equation),
$$
n_{\ce{A}} \mathrm{d}\mu_{\ce{A}} + n_{\ce{B}} \mathrm{d}\mu_{\ce{B}} = 0,
$$
which means that $\mu_{\ce{A}}$ changes upon adding B to the mixture, even when the partial pressure of A is constant. This contradicts the formula.

Comment: Who says that the partial pressure of A is constant when you add B to the mixture at constant pressure?

Comment: I meant adding b at constant volume of the mixture

Answer (score 1):

The chemical potential of a the two species in your ideal gas mixture are $$\mu_A=\mu^0_A(T)+RT\ln\left(P\frac{n_A}{(n_A+n_B)}\right)$$
$$\mu_B=\mu^0_B(T)+RT\ln\left(P\frac{n_B}{(n_A+n_B)}\right)$$
and the total free energy of the mixture is:
$$G=n_A\mu_A+n_B\mu_B$$So, the chemical potential of A depends on the number of moles of B and the chemical potential of B depends on the number of moles of A.  Do these equations satisfy the Gibbs-Duhem equation?  Try them out and see.

Comment: I also had one more aspect in my question as to how can we arrive at this equation for mixtures. because deriving it is straightforward for one component systems but not for mixtures.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking here.  Are you asking about your third equation, and where it comes from?

Comment: no i mean the logarithmic dependence of chemical potential... how do you reach to that in the case of mixtures..

Comment: I still need a little more clarification.  Are you asking how I know that the chemical potential of a species in an ideal gas mixture is determined by the log of its partial pressure in the mixture?  Are you familiar with the change in entropy between an ideal gas mixture at T and P, and the same amounts of pure species, each at P and T?

Comment: I just need a simple derivation of the explicit expression of u if possible from the expression of G=VdP-SdT+u(a)dn(a)+u(b)dn(b)..

Comment: if youre asking about the gibbs energy of mixing and the associated entropy change then yes..

Comment: You're familiar with Gibbs' theorem that the contribution of each species in an ideal gas mixture to an overall extensive property of a mixture is equal to that of the pure species as the same temperature and at its partial pressure in the mixture?

Comment: Suppose I asked you to derive the equation for the entropy change between the following two ideal gas states:  (1)  na moles of pure A at T and P, and nb moles of pure B at T and P.  (2) (na+nb) moles of a mixture of A and B at T and P.  Could you do it?  What would be your answer?

Comment: thanks a lot for your help @chester miller. But it would be great if you could provide me a link to the proof or intuition behind the Gibbs Theorem.because it explains quite a lot of things...

Comment: I don't have an online link, but I can provide a book reference:  Introduction to Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics by Smith and McCabe.  Here is a question for you:  If I have an ideal gas mixture containing species A and an ideal semi-permeable membrane that is permeable only to A, what pressure of pure A do I have to apply on the other side of the membrane so that the mixture is in equilibrium with the pure A?

Comment: that is precisely the point i was hitting on. even semipermeable membranes should maintain same potential rather than same pressure on both sides. but in light of the gibbs theorem it all makes sense as same pressure implies same potential. anyways thanks for your help sorry for the late reply.